# High performing Bitmap Drawing solution in c#

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, bitmap, gdi+

I have a use case where I need to render a collage of bitmaps as a preview. The application is implemented as a MVC based REST service, and I have a fairly vanilla implementation:

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap((int)maxWidth, (int)maxHeight))
{
using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    // now again for each mod
    foreach (var mod in mods)
    {
        var frame = frames.First(f => f.Index == mod.FrameIndex);
        var fileInfo = GetFileInfo(mod);
        using (var modImage = Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName))
        {
            graphic.DrawImage(modImage, (int)frame.Left, (int)frame.Top);
        }
    }

    bitmap.Save(previewFileName);
}
}
```

While this code works fine, it performs very poorly (especially with larger images). I am open to using third party libraries as well, I just need a faster performing solution.

Any help would be mostly appreciated.

**Update**

To clarify the use case, caching doesn't help. These images are uploaded by the customer, then they request a preview of the selected collage. It's the writing of the images to the collage that is slow.

Comment: So it's a web application. What is the image format you transfer the images in? Just to make sure that only the drawing is your problem and not the bandwidth. A System.Drawing.Bitmap can be anything from RAW BMP to PNG, GIF, JPEG, etc.

Comment: I don't expect to support RAW, but all others are fair game. The images are being uploaded by customers.

Answer (score 1):

I just now realized that you're drawing the modImages in their original size (because you're using the override that only takes a left and top coordinate). If that's what you want, you could as well just use the DrawImageUnscaled()-Method of the graphics class, that should be much faster:

```
    var frame = frames.First(f => f.Index == mod.FrameIndex);
    var fileInfo = GetFileInfo(mod);
    using (var modImage = Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName))
    {
        graphic.DrawImageUnscaled(modImage, (int)frame.Left, (int)frame.Top);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How important is the image quality? If you need faster results, you should try InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbour, this should be much faster, but results will be rather low-quality.
HeighQualityBicubic (what you're currently using) produces best results, but at lowest performance.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need the highest quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static number of Thumbnails, similar to Netflix, I would create a Cache in memory that keeps the thumbnail bitmaps.  This could even be a static object.  Once you have generated the thumbnail, you never need to generate it again.  It would be a cleaner approach than trying to find a faster hammer to hit it with every time.

Example :

```
if(MyThumbnailImageDictionary["whateverimageId"] != null)
   return (Bitmap)MyThumbnailImageDictionary["whateverimageId"];
```

If the thumbnails are dynamic such as from a user uploading random pictures, then this method will not help as the size of the image cache will grow tremendous.

You can use the following code to generate a Thubnail, but I am not sure how much faster it would be :

```
 Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
 Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(120, 120, ()=>false, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help. This doesn't just happen once, this happens on demand as requested by customers. Each customer can request multiple of these.

Comment: I have edited my post to make the use case for the optimization clear, and an alternative.  Try it and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. I have added an explanation on the original post. I actually already have thumbnails